# Uploader fo image. JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have some problem in my task. I created asp.net mvc project and upload image to server. For upload I use swfupload. There is code for create uploader:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#photo").makeAsyncUploader({
      upload_url: "/Home/AsyncUpload/<%= ViewData["guid"]%>",
      flash_url: '/Scripts/swfupload.swf',
      button_image_url: '/Content/blankButton.png',
      disableDuringUpload: 'INPUT[type="submit"]'
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is for one button with name "photo". But must have more buttons with name "photo1" "photo2"... I created script for add to div new input:

```
<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add new button"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function add() {
    var newelement = document.createElement('p');
    newelement.setAttribute("class", "file_input");
    var x = ((document.getElementById('uploadImage').getElementsByTagName('p').length));
    var fileinput = document.createElement('input');
    fileinput.setAttribute("name", "photo" + x);
    fileinput.setAttribute("type", "file");
    newelement.appendChild(fileinput);
    document.getElementById('uploadImage').appendChild(new_element);
  }
</script>
```

It is working. and it add button to my div

```
<div id="uploadImage">
  <p>Photo: <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo"/> </p>                                                                              
</div>
```

I have question, what should be a script that when I add a new button it will swfupload. Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly your add() function should look like this:

```
<script>
var uploadButtonCount = 0;
function add() {
   var uploadButtonId = "photo" + uploadButtonCount++;
   var uploadInput = $('<input id="' + uploadButtonId + '" type="file" name="photo"/>');
   $("#uploadImage").append(uploadInput);

   uploadInput.makeAsyncUploader({
         upload_url: "/Home/AsyncUpload/<%= ViewData["guid"]%>",
         flash_url: '/Scripts/swfupload.swf',
         button_image_url: '/Content/blankButton.png',
         disableDuringUpload: 'INPUT[type="submit"]'
   });
}
</script>
```

You need to pass your newly created input with unique id to the plugin.